# Troubles with setting ToolTip duration programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip

I've come across a situtation where I need to create a tooltip object and show it when the user hovers over specific areas in my application.

I can get the tooltip to show up just fine. The problem is I need it to go poof after a few seconds have passed.  I'm aware of the `ToolTipService.SetShowDuration` and I've tried using it, but I have not been met with much luck.

Here's what I got in my MouseMove event handler:

```
_toolTip.Placement = PlacementMode.Relative;
_toolTip.Horizontal = e.X;
_toolTip.VerticalOffset = e.Y;
_toolTip.Content = stuffs;
_toolTip.IsOpen = true;
```

I've tried setting the following:

```
someObject.ToolTip = _toolTip;
ToolTipService.SetShowDuration(someObject, 5);
```

Nothing changes with the last two lines. The tooltip still is visible and stays visible.  Am I using the service wrong or something? Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: What about pushing the code into MouseEnter event and not MouseOver? Did you try this?

Comment: My mistake, it's in the MouseMove event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a workaround for the issue.

To give a little more background, I have a 3D model of an aircraft inside of a WindowsFormsHost object. When the user hovers over a identified part, I needed a tooltip to appear.

I created an instance of tooltip and in my MouseMove event and I do something like this:

```
// selectedPart will be null if no part is selected
if(selectedPart != null && prevSelectedPart != selectedPart)
{
    toolTip.IsOpen = false;
    host.ToolTip = toolTip;
    toolTip.IsOpen = true;
}
else if (prevSelectedPart == selectedPart  && prevSelectedPart != null)
{
    toolTip.IsOpen = true;
}
else
    toolTip.IsOpen = false;
```

That does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 <Border Name="border" ToolTip="some message" MouseEnter="border_MouseEnter" Background="red" Margin="50"/>

  ToolTip tool = new ToolTip();
        private void border_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
        tool.Placement = PlacementMode.Relative;
        tool.HorizontalOffset = 100; 
        tool.VerticalOffset = 200;
        tool.Content = "stuffs";
        tool.IsOpen = true;
        border.ToolTip = tool;
        ToolTipService.SetShowDuration(border, 5000);
        }
```

Comment: I have to create the ToolTip object programmatically. When I do so, The ToolTipService.SetShowDuration doesn't seem to help :(

Comment: with your edit, does the tooltip disappear after 5 seconds? I've tried this before, but it didn't work. :(